# hg serve for subrepos

Tags: mercurial, webserver, subrepos

I have a repo with subrepos, and would like to do `hg serve`.

On other computer, I tried

```
hg clone http://address:8000/ new_repo
```

Scenario 1: when my original repo had, in .hgsub, lines of the form:

```
sub_repo_1 = sub_repo_1
sub_repo_2 = sub_repo_2
```

I got on other computer:

```
Requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
...
updating to branch default
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

(the serve computer just waits after that)

(and only the sub_repo_1 inside new_repo. I have tried update, pull... with errors)

I have tried to actually clone separately sub_repo_2, and kept getting Error 404 (bot on sending and receiving computer).

Scenario 2: Same thing happened when I replaced in .hgsub the lines with

```
sub_repo_1 = http://address/sub_repo_1
sub_repo_2 = http://address/sub_repo_2
```

Is hg serve unable to serve subrepos ? Or - what am I doing wrong ?

Note: I have updated the hgrc files inside the subrepos to match the paths in the .hgsub, each time.

Comment: I would like to do the same. I am thinking about hacking hg serve?!?!

Answer (score 2):

You can use TortoiseHG to host a mercurial server for a repository that has subrepositories. TortoiseHG actually calls hg serve with a different web.config file it creates.

To host using TortoiseHG, go to Repository -> Web Server... in TortoiseHG Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

`hg serve` works with subrepos. The thing is that `hg serve` doesn't automagically recognize that your repo contains subrepos.

Supposing that there's the following folder structure

```
- repo
  - subrepo1
    + file1.txt
  - subrepo2
    + file2.txt
    + file3.txt
```

Where *repo* is the main repository and *subrepo1* and *subrepo2* are two subrepositories of *repo*:

1. Create a web configuration file inside *repo*. **Do not add it** in version control. I called it .hgwebconf, you can change the name if you want.
2. Configure all paths for subrepos in this file. Add the following content:

   ```
   [paths]
   /repo = ./* #all repos will be known by the url /repo
   /repo/subrepo1 = subrepo1 #adding subrepo1 to be available in hg serve
   /repo/subrepo2 = subrepo2 #similar to above
   ```
3. Execute `hg serve` using `--web-conf` property to use the web configuration file created for the paths. Here's an example:

   ```
   hg serve --web-conf .hgwebconf <other configurations you use ...>
   ```

And that's it. Now you could access to your server vía http, clone your repo or any subrepo and work with it.

Comment: I have so often fought against making subrepos work with hg serve. I can't believe the solution is so simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am using `HgService` to host the repositories and it's the solution I found working.

If you are using `HgService`, you'll need to edit the `web.config` file and restart the service.

If the `[paths]` in the `web.config` is setup like this:

```
[paths]
remote_repo = "path/to/remote_repo"
```

Add the double star (`**`) to the path like this:

```
[paths]
remote_repo = "path/to/remote_repo/**"
```